# I want to link a javascript array from another website so i can process it

Tags: javascript

```js
const countries = require("https://ninjahosting.ninjablade.repl.co/jsHosting/script.js");
let n = 0;
while (n < 198) {
  n++;
  setTimeout(()=>{document.getElementById(elementId).value = countries[(n+1)]; }, delay*n);
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error

> "41:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

https://jsfiddle.net/6xnqhosk/

That's the fiddle

Comment: What JS version are you using? I think you can use ES6 modules to import, export, e.t.c.

Comment: your script does not assign your array to any variable.
the module.export misses an s (if it was meant to be run in node).
Can't you just rename your file as a json and only put your json array in it ?

Comment: You can't use `require` in the browser without some build tool. In this case you're better off using a normal `fetch` request.

Comment: I don't understand what ur saying